# When does derived pullback commute with infinite products?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, cohomology, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of reasonable schemes (qcqs). Let $f^*: D(Y) \to D(X)$ be the pullback defined on the derived unbounded categories of quasi-coherent sheaves.

> Question: **When does $f^*$ commute with arbitrary products?**

Comment: This happens iff $f^*$ is a right adjoint. I think that the go-to answer is that it happens if $f$ is smooth. I am not sure if you can say anything in other situations.

Comment: @DenisNardin I was under the impression infinite products don't even commute with restriction to open subsets.

Comment: @DenisNardin For instance i'm pretty sure a counterexample is the sheaf $\prod_n k[t]/t^n k[t]$ pulled back along $\mathbb{A}^1 - 0$

Comment: You might also be interested in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01999, where $f^*$ having a left adjoint is called a Grothendieck--Neeman duality situation, see theorem 1.7. This is closely related to the answer of Marc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functor $f^*: D(Y) \to D(X)$ preserves limits if $Y$ is noetherian and $f$ is proper flat with Gorenstein fibers, for example if $f$ is smooth and proper. Under these assumptions: $f^!$ is right adjoint to $f_*$ by properness, $f^!(\mathcal F)=f^!(\mathcal O_Y)\otimes f^*(\mathcal F)$ by finite tor-amplitude, and $f^!(\mathcal O_Y)$ is invertible by Gorenstein. Hence, $f^*$ is right adjoint to $f_*(f^!\mathcal O_Y\otimes -)$.

See http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C02 for a discussion of Gorenstein morphisms, particularly Lemma 45.43.8, and section 7 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7599v1.pdf for the relevant properties of $f^!$.

**ETA** According to pbelmans' comment above, the Gorenstein assumption is not actually needed: if $Y$ is arbitrary and $f$ is proper, pseudo-coherent, and of finite tor-amplitude, then $f^*$ is right adjoint to $f_*(f^!\mathcal O_Y\otimes -)$. Combine Corollary 6.4.2.7 in http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/SAG-rootfile.pdf and Theorem 1.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01999.